# Послал триста/трёхсот стрельцов

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные, родительный-или-винительный

> *Царь послал **триста** стрельцов в Москву.*

Или всё-таки "трёхсот"? Почему-то ничего не нашёл в интернете на эту тему.

Предположу, что основной вариант *"триста",* а вариант *"трёхсот"* можно выбрать, если вдруг этих стрельцов кто-то поголовно знает и акцент на том, что именно этих он послал, а не триста произвольных.

Comment: За что минус? Совесть имейте!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, конечно, только "триста".

Сначала хотел было отделаться комментарием типа *"Трехсот - это родительный падеж. Откуда ему взяться при прямом дополнении без отрицания?"*, но посмотрел уже данные ответы и комментарии к ним...

Есть несколько групп глаголов, которые допускают или даже требуют родительного падежа в роли прямого дополнения, основную массу которых составляют "ждательные"  глаголы ("ждать трамвая/трамвай и "партитивные" - выпить воды/воду), но это явно не наш случай.

Что касается причин появления такой неправильности, то тут имею своё объяснение. Дело не в смешении с формами при "более/менее", а в том, что налицо одушевленный субъект (стрельцы), то есть винительный падеж должен бы совпадать с родительным. Но количественно-именная группа теряет категорию одушевленности, подчиняется правилам использования неодушевленных имен и требует формы родительного только тогда, когда это и есть родительный. Это, как верно пишет Екатерина, происходит, например, при отрицании.

Или в случае приименного родительного: Решение трехсот жильцов дома.

Так что проще всего уяснить, что "триста стрельцов, бойцов, крестоносцев или китайцев" - они как "триста концов, дворцов, перцев или авианосцев". У вас не повернется язык сказать "построил трёхсот дворцов" или "послал трёхсот авианосцев"?

Comment: *У вас не повернется язык сказать "построил трёхсот дворцов" или "послал трёхсот авианосцев"?* Нееет))) *Так что проще всего уяснить что "триста стрельцов, бойцов, крестоносцев или китайцев" - они как "триста концов, дворцов, перцев или авианосцев".* Так и сделаю, спасибо! Большой абзац очень хорошо объясняет мои недоумения!

Answer (score 4):

Цельное неделимое количественно-именное сочетание ***триста стрельцов*** в данном предложениии употреблено в винительном падеже: послал (кого? что?) триста стрельцов.

***Царь послал (кого? что?) триста стрельцов в Москву.***

Родительный падеж здесь практически невозможен, так как от сказуемого ***послал*** к сочетанию ***триста стрельцов*** вопрос ***кого? чего?*** задать, мягко говоря, сложно. Ср.: ***послал маслица*** (часть целого - родительный падеж).

***Нет (кого? чего?) трёхсот стрельцов.*** Здесь всё цельное количественно-именное сочетание ***трёхсот стрельцов*** употреблено в родительном падеже.

***Царь не посылал трёхсот стрельцов (и триста стрельцов).*** Оба варианта возможны при наличии отрицания при глаголе.

Comment: *так как от сказуемого послал к сочетанию триста стрельцов вопрос кого? чего? задать,мягко говоря, сложно* - да запросто. *Царь послал трехсот стрельцов к такой-то матери*.

Comment: Вehemothus, извините, **нельзя** сказать "послал трехсот стрельцов" (уже все равно — куда). Нет у "чистого" глагола "послать" такого управления.

Comment: @behemothus А если стрельцов сто или, скажем, миллион? Думаю, Вас здесь чутьё подводит.

Comment: "grizzly вам смайлик нужен был? С тысячей и миллионом не проходит, поскольку это единственное число. А с двумя или тремя тысячами - в самый раз.

Comment: *нельзя сказать "послал трехсот стрельцов"*  - мда... И вы туда же... Обещаю больше так тонко не шутить.

Answer (score 3):

> > *Царь послал триста стрельцов в Москву.*
>
> Или всё-таки "трёхсот"? Почему-то ничего не нашёл в интернете на эту
>   тему.

Из комментария в этой теме:

> Вот только интересно, "трёхсот" вообще никогда не используется?

**Практически не используется.**

Ирина Микаэлян в работе *"О категории одушевлённости в конструкциях с числительными в русском языке"* пишет про одушевленные формы числительных *двести, триста* и *четыреста*:

> Числительные *двести, триста* и *четыреста* **теоретически** могут
>   использоваться в форме *вин = род*, хотя в современном языке
>   практически исключительно встречаются несогласованные формы *вин = им*
>   (ср. Мельчук 1985: 204).
>
> http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/melchuk_festschrift2012/Mikaelian.pdf

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!

Answer (score 2):

[посла́ть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)
**1. *(кого-что)***, с инф. Отправить куда-либо с каким-либо поручением, направить с какой-либо целью.

Думаю, что правильно использовать **винительный падеж**.
*Царь послал **триста** стрельцов в Москву.*

> Дело в том, что сын Кипсела Периандр **послал** было в Сарды к Алиатту для оскопления **триста мальчиков**, детей знатнейших людей с острова Керкиры ([Геродот](https://books.google.ee/books?id=yP4lDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT408&lpg=PT408&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=4jNjyIVaRn&sig=ACfU3U2JRbqddN6zGxPVx5Thv9dXJ4S_qg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR1L252-bpAhVE6KYKHe3fCpQQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false)).
>
> Последние речи уже окончательно рассердили воеводу, и он **послал двести рейтаров** и две пушки (В. Ян. Молотобойцы).
>
> Он кинулся к муравейнику, лаем разбудил всё население и **послал четыреста муравьёв** — перегрызть верёвку, на которой висел Буратино (А. Толстой).

[Склонение имен числительных](http://ebooks.grsu.by/ruslang/sklonenie-imen-chislitelnykh.htm)

**Дополнение**

Я пересмотрела [все](http://www.endic.ru/ushakov/Poslat-54667.html) словари — родительный падеж нигде не указан.
Возможно, сомнения возникли в связи с тем, что Р. п. требуется при употреблении перед счетным оборотом слов *более (не более), менее (не менее), около.*

> Навстречу им Мемнон **послал около трехсот** бойцов, вооруженных дротиками и мечами (А. Ахматов. Триокала. Исторический роман).
> Марксу я уже **послал около двухсот** рассказов новых, т. е. еще не помещенных в сборниках, да почти столько же мною брошено за негодностью (из письма А. Чехова).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Вот только интересно, "трёхсот" **вообще никогда** не используется?

Comment: Странно. Вы же спрашивали только про глагол "послать" — какое-либо отрицание не подразумевалось. Если есть родительный падеж (а он есть), то, конечно же, он где-нибудь (с каким-нибудь другим глаголом) и употребляется. Но в вопросе это не отражено. Вопрос один — о выборе падежа. Ответ один — винительный.

Comment: Я просто предположил, что именно с "послал" может быть родительный падеж, если стрельцы, допустим, более определённые. А вот проясните мне, пожалуйста, такую вещь: почему в сокращении падежа надо сам падеж писать с большой буквы? Никогда не понимал.

Comment: Хотите — задайте **_сообществу_** отдельный вопрос (по поводу Р. п.). Я же сломала перья и умыла руки (это — в подражание _бегемотусу_: «Обещаю больше так тонко не шутить»).

Comment: А ваше-то мнение какое (по поводу большой буквы)? Почему выбираете её?

Comment: Ответите мне, Римма?

Comment: Извините, Артём, что не смогла **сразу** Вам ответить (но я _видела_ сообщения): сначала сдерживали временные рамки, а потом — отсутствие компьютера. Вижу, что вопрос про падеж разрешился. Извините еще раз.

Comment: Ничего страшного, Римма. Но меня всё-таки интересует Ваше мнение: почему выбираете большую букву. :)

Comment: Думаю, что такая привычка у меня осталась еще со школьных времен. Новейший справочник школьника (стр. 686) тоже использует такое сокращение: _у дороги_ — ж. р., ед. ч., Р. п. (ссылка объемная — в комментарий не вмещается).  Орфографический словарь (http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=266) не запрещает. Род, река, рубль, родился — эти слова сокращенно  можно записать как **р.** Я посчитала, что пусть уж падеж будет **Р.**

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вот еще один справочник (с заглавными буквами): https://books.google.ee/books?id=jSsqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%D1%83+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8+%E2%80%94+%D0%B6.+%D1%80.,+%D0%B5%D0%B4.+%D1%87.,+%D0%A0.+%D0%BF.&source=bl&ots=jpeoTliVKv&sig=ACfU3U15etf7DyHI3ht7YQwuL6YvFYhKFA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO8rSBj_PpAhXRxIsKHd7bDkMQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B6.%20%D1%80.%2C%20%D0%B5%D0%B4.%20%D1%87.%2C%20%D0%A0.%20%D0%BF.&f=false Я ведь не филолог — только пытаюсь _немного_ поучаствовать...

Comment: Спасибо, что поделились своим видением, Римма!