# Цельное количественно-именное словосочетание или свободное сочетание слов?

Tags: синтаксис

Встретился в одном из ответов в теме [***Послал триста/трёхсот стрельцов***](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461038/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2) такой разбор:

> ***Нет*** (кого? чего?) ***трёхсот стрельцов.*** Здесь всё цельное количественно-именное сочетание ***трёхсот стрельцов*** употреблено в
>   родительном падеже.

При таком подходе *трёхсот стрельцов* следовало бы считать дополнением.

**Но есть ли в разбираемом предложении цельное количественно-именное сочетание?** Может, *трёхсот* здесь следует считать определением к дополнению *стрельцов*?

**Вера Васильевна Бабайцева** в книге *"Система членов предложения в современном русском языке"* (М., 2011) пишет:

> Для количественно-именных словосочетаний типа *три пальмы, много
>   песен, несколько шагов* характерны комплетивные отношения... В
>   словосочетаниях этого вида "главенствует" своеобразная форма
>   существительного при числительном в формах именительного и
>   винительного падежей. **Сочетание числительного с существительным в
>   формах остальных падежей остаётся свободным** (выделение полужирным здесь и далее в цитате — моё. — slava1947), причём главным словом
>   является существительное. Ср.: *Я купила **три книги**.* — цельное
>   словосочетание в функции прямого дополнения; *Мы говорили **о трёх
>   книгах***. — свободное сочетание слов (***о книгах*** — дополнение,
>   ***трёх*** — согласованное определение).

Как я понимаю, с точки зрения Бабайцевой в предложении ***Нет трёхсот стрельцов*** нет цельного словосочетания, т. е. имеет место свободное сочетание слов.

**А существуют ли учебные пособия с отличным от приведённого Бабайцевой взглядом на количественно-именные словосочетания?   Т. е. относят ли какие-либо пособия сочетания в косвенных падежах типа *трёх стрельцов, трём стрельцам, о трёх стрельцах*  к цельным?**

Comment: А в тексте В. Бабайцевой есть выделение Жирным и Курсивом? Или...

Comment: _shampar: А в тексте В. Бабайцевой есть выделение Жирным и Курсивом? Или..._ === Нет, ни жирного, ни полужирного шрифта в приведённой мной цитате в книге нет. Курсив есть. Есть и подчёркивание определений и дополнений, которые нельзя воспроизвести на этом сайте. **Выделение полужирным** — моё.